# Space in less loop

Tags: css, less

I have this :

```
.loop(@index) when(@index =< @to) {
    .page-@{index} {
        nav{
            ul{
                li:nth-child(@{index}){
                    background:#fff;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .loop(@index + 1);
}
```

It seems to have a problem, because the output of my css is :

```
ul li:nth-child( 2) {
  background: #fff;
}
ul li:nth-child( 3) {
  background: #fff;
}
```

it creates a space in the pseudo selector and it doesn't work.
Any ideas to remove this space ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug. A workaround is to set the identifier via temporary variable, e.g.:

```
ul {
    @li: ~"li:nth-child(@{index})";
    @{li} {
        background: #fff;
    }
}
```