# How do I make a list of CSS rules in LESS based on an unknown number of input arguments?

Tags: less

I'd like to make a LESS mixin for translating images like so:

```
.translate('/images/image.png', de, en-uk);
```

with an output that looks like this:

```
background-image: url('/images/image.png');
&:lang(de){ background-image: url('/images/image_de.png') }
&:lang(en-uk){ background-image: url('/images/image_en-uk.png') }
```

This would be easy if we were always translating the same number of languages, but unfortunately we are not (the content is the same across certain locales). I'm not sure how to make this number variable (which would future-proof the solution).

I guess what I'm looking for is a way to loop over each element in an array I pass and return another LESS rule for each.

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to have one source language, and one or more target languages?

Comment: Something like `.translate(@image; @fromLang; @targetLangs...)` where the last argument could have many?

Comment: Hi @helderdarocha - just one source language. .translate() is probably the wrong name for the mixin, it's just replacing the filenames for images (_target1, _target2). Assume the picture without a language suffix is the source language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Variadic mixin arguments](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-advanced-arguments-and-the-coderestcode-variable), [Loops](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature), [List Functions](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions). For example it could be implemented somewhat like:

```css
.test {
    .translate('/images/image.png', grc, lat, san);
}

.translate(@image, @langs...) {
    background-image: @image;
    .-(length(@langs));
    .-(@i) when (@i > 0) {
        .-((@i - 1));
        @lang: extract(@langs, @i);
        &:lang(@{lang}) {
            background-image: replace(@image, "\.", "_@{lang}.");
        }
    }
}
```

[`replace`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-replace) function requires Less 1.7.0 but for earlier versions you can use plain string [interpolation/concatenation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation) or [format function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-format) as in @helderdarocha answer.

(Also note that the `@langs...` mixin parameter above can also accept the language list as a single variable), e.g.:

```less
@languages: de, fr, es, ru, en-uk; // in fact commas here are optional too 

.test {
    .translate('/images/image.png', @languages);
}
```

---

And just in case, the same mixin using [`for`](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/src/for.less) wrapper (just to show that Less loops don't have to be that scary :):

```css
@import "for";

.translate(@image, @langs...) {
    background-image: @image;
    .for(@langs); .-each(@lang) {
        &:lang(@{lang}) {
            background-image: replace(@image, "\.", "_@{lang}.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi seven-phases-max, thanks for the awesome answer. It does exactly what I'm after, and it's very clean (especially with the for loop). I must admit, it's a bit magic to me, I find both implementations kind of hard to follow. Also: i'm left with "&:lang( en), &:lang( en-uk) etc. (with a leading space) in my output. This works in Chrome but I wonder if it could cause problems. How can we trim the space without removing it from the mixin call ('/path/image.png', en, en-uk)?

Comment: It's probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23064609/2712740) bug. Though the examples do not suffer from it, some further class nesting could probably cause that redundant space. The workaround is the same as there: put class name into temporary variable, e.g. `@name: ~':lang(@{lang})'; &@{name} {...}`.

Answer (score 2):

This mixin uses target languages from a variable. It will loop through them and generate the code you want for each one:

```css
.image-replace(@languages; @image-prefix) {
  @count: length(@languages);
  .loop(@count; @image-prefix);
  .loop(@count; @image-prefix) when (@count > 0) {
    .loop(@count - 1; @image-prefix);
    @lang: extract(@languages, @count);
    @image: %('%a_%a.png', @image-prefix, @lang);
    &:lang(@{lang}){
      background-image: url(@image);
    }
  }
}
```

To use it:

```css
@languages: ~'de', ~'fr', ~'es', ~'ru', ~'en-UK', ~'pt-BR';
.section {
  .image-replace(@languages; ~'/images/image');
}
```

Result:

```css
.section:lang(de) {
  background-image: url('/images/image_de.png');
}
.section:lang(fr) {
  background-image: url('/images/image_fr.png');
}
.section:lang(es) {
  background-image: url('/images/image_es.png');
}
.section:lang(ru) {
  background-image: url('/images/image_ru.png');
}
.section:lang(en-UK) {
  background-image: url('/images/image_en-UK.png');
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure what to make of this line:
`.translate(5; ~'/images/image');`

It looks like I have to list the number of languages I'm inputting, which is better than nothing but in my eyes would kind of defeat the purpose. Or am I missing something?

You've also listed 6 languages in the array and given the output for 5. Was that deliberate or a typo?

Comment: I actually wrote it very fast and didn't check that. The intention was to replace the number for the `length()` function which can get the number of languages but I forgot to do that. I edited the answer above with these changes. I changed `translate` for `image-replace` too.

Comment: Hi, I actually find your answer slightly easier to follow (less magic), but gave the accepted answer to seven-phases for its conciseness and for the .for solution. I upvoted your answer too for what it's worth. Keep on LESSing!